# How to set app configuration property dynamically?

Tags: angular

I have a `config.json` file under `assets/config/config.json` which I use to load upon launching the app.

I am reading a property from it called `version` to display the version of my app on the homepage.

I want to implement a feature that will let a user change the version number of the app via a button on the UI. For that when user clicks on the button, I want to change the config property `version` from `config.json` file and assign the user provided value to it.

How do I load the user provided value to `config.json` file?

this is what my configuration service looks like,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Configuration } from './configuration';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigurationService {
  private configData: Configuration | undefined;
  private readonly configPath: string = '/assets/config/configuration.json';
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  async loadConfiguration(): Promise {
    try {
      const response = await this.http.get(`${this.configPath}`)
        .toPromise();
      this.configData = response;
      return this.configData;
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  }

  get config(): {
    return this.configData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Noted. I have edited my tags.